# Child class as a return type of parent class

Tags: java

In `Test` class `Object` is used with `show` method. If we write the `Object` with the `show` method of `xyz` class, so will it be wrong. I am confused here that Object is the parent class of all the classes. Can it be used any where.

```
class Test{
        Object show(){
        System.out.println("1");
        }
    }
    class xyz extends Test{
        String show(){
        System.out.println("2");
        }
    }
```

If i write the above code as

```
class Test{
        String show(){
        System.out.println("1");
        }
    }
    class xyz extends Test{
        Object show(){
        System.out.println("2");
        }
    }
```

If Object holds all classes or Object is the `parent` class of all classes so, does it matter where we use it?

Comment: I am beginner in java plz give me the examples.

Comment: This code won't compile.

Comment: My main question is this why in xyz class String is used

Comment: I know that Object is the parent class of all the class but in xyz class why the other data types are not used

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As of Java 5, method overriding allows *co-variant* return types meaning the overriden method of the subclass can return a type which is more specific but still assignable to the parent method return type.

In this case since the parent method is returning `Object` the child method can in fact return a `String` which is a sub-class of `Object` and is assignable to it.

From the [JLS specs](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-8.html#jls-8.4.5):

> Return types may vary among methods that override each other if the
>   return types are reference types. The notion of
>   return-type-substitutability supports covariant returns, that is, the
>   specialization of the return type to a subtype.

If you try this with `CharSequence` in the parent class method and say an `Integer` in the child class method it won't compile:

```
class Test{
    CharSequence show(){
        System.out.println("1");
        return null;
    }
}
class xyz extends Test{
    Integer show(){  //won't compile
        System.out.println("2");
        return null;
    }
}
```

But replace the `Integer` with `String` it would compile as `String` implements / is a type of `CharSequence` :

```
class Test{
    CharSequence show(){
        System.out.println("1");
        return null;
    }
}
class xyz extends Test{
    String show(){
        System.out.println("2");
        return null;
    }
}
```